# How do I disable vetur linting in vscode workspace?

Tags: vue.js, visual-studio-code, workspace

I Have a VS code workspace and Vetur is throwing error because my Vue folder is not at the root so it thinks it is a Vue 2 project. How can I disable Vetur linting?

I added this to my .vscode/settings.json

```
{
    "vetur.validation.template": false,
    "vetur.validation.script": false,
    "vetur.validation.style": false,
}
```

As described in the docs

```
https://vuejs.github.io/vetur/linting-error.html#error-checking
```

But it give the message

```
This setting cannot be applied in this workspace. It will be applied when you open the containing workspace folder directly.
```

Which kinda defeats the purpose

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Turns out you can just add it to your global vscode settings

```
F1>Preferences:Open Settings (JSON)
```

paste

```
"vetur.validation.template": false,
"vetur.validation.script": false,
"vetur.validation.style": false,
```

For a better understand.
[image]